# Save common Grep patterns in bashrc

Tags: bash, grep

I frequently do grep that matches the following pattern

```
grep -irs "main" . --exclude-dir={env,build,release-info} --include \*.java
```

I am trying to find if I can save this pattern to my bashrc, so that I don't have to type the huge grep line each time.

To the grep alias in the bashc, I am looking to pass the following as parameters.

1. SearchString
2. `--include` pattern. Can I have `*.java` as default value? If a different value is passed override the default value.
3. Similarly, can I have `--exclude-dir` to have a default value. If a value is passed, override the default value.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Sure, easiest way to do this is to define [shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html).  I'm not exactly sure how you want your parameters to work.  Bash is more annoying to work with than a real programming language, but you can certainly get this going.

Comment: I was trying to get this through bash. Shell functions seems to be a better option. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Shell functions are a feature of `bash` :).  I linked you to appropriate docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your .bashrc could look quite simple:

```
function mygrep {
    s=${1:-"main"}
    e=${2:-"env,build,release-info"}
    i=${3:-"\*.java"}
    grep -irs "$s" . "--exclude-dir={$e}" --include "$i"
}
```

The assignments are the standard way of defining variable defaults.

Here are some usage examples (for debugging purpose, I had put a `set -x` around my grep statement in *.bashrc*):

```
~/$ mygrep
+ grep -irs main . '--exclude-dir={env,build,release-info}' --include '\*.java'
~/$ mygrep some
+ grep -irs some . '--exclude-dir={env,build,release-info}' --include '\*.java'
~/$ mygrep some otherexclude
+ grep -irs some . '--exclude-dir={otherexclude}' --include '\*.java'
~/$ mygrep some otherexclude "otherinclude1 otherinclude2"
+ grep -irs some . '--exclude-dir={otherexclude}' --include 'otherinclude1 otherinclude2'
~/$ mygrep "" "" "otherinclude1 otherinclude2"
+ grep -irs main . '--exclude-dir={env,build,release-info}' --include 'otherinclude1 otherinclude2'
~/$ mygrep "" "otherexclude"
+ grep -irs main . '--exclude-dir={otherexclude}' --include '\*.java'
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, use shell functions. The exact function depends a bit on what kind of interface you want.

As an example:

```
grepmain(){
    if [ "$excldir" = "" ] ; then
        grepmainexcl="env,build,release-info"
    else
        grepmainexcl="$excldir"
    fi
    grep -irs "main" . "--exclude-dir={$grepmainexcl}" --include "$@"
}
```

and use it as:

```
grepmain \*.java
excldir=env,build grepmain \*.java
```

You can also use flags like `-e` for excludedir on your function; if others will use it, you would probably want to include some validity-checks in the function as well.